# Why there is no optional(nil) but only nil?

Tags: swift, null, option-type

Given the follwoing code example:

```
var ResponseCode: Int? = 404
print(ResponseCode) // --> Optional(404)
ResponseCode = nil
print(ResponseCode) // --> nil (why not Optional(nil)?)
```

**Question**: why when I printed a nil-valued option it is just a `nil`. Why not also showing the `Optional(nil)`

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather simple to explain. `Optional` is an enum that has two values: `.Some(T)` and `.None`.

As you see, only one of them has a parameter.

The string description of `.Some(T)` is `"Optional(description of T)"`. `.None` has no parameters so the description is just `nil`.

Note you can sometimes see `"Optional(nil)"` in your log, however, in that case we are dealing with double optionals (e.g. `Int??`).

```
print(Optional<Int?>(Optional<Int>.None)) // prints "Optional(nil)"
```

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation, good to know that Optional is actually an enum

Answer (score 3):

Because `nil` is a constant literal meaning `Option.None`.

Allowing an Optional to store a nil value wouldn't make sense, and would completely defeat the purpose (enforcement of non-nullability) of Optionals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and argument.

Comment: It does not really defeat the purpose, we have double optionals, too.

Comment: @sulthan Yes, but I meant it in the context of a single Optional. It would break their contract.